# What is the characteristic subgroup of $ S_{3} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

What is the characteristic subgroup of $ S_{3} $ such that $ S_{3} $ is the symmetric subgroup of degree $ 3 $

Answer (score 3):

In general there is no *the* characteristic subgroup. Recall that a subgroup of $G$ is called characteristic if it is invariant under all automorphisms of $G$. So $\{1\}$ and $G$ are always among the characteristic subgroups. Apart from those, $G=S_3$ has only two kinds of subgroup: Those of order $2$ and the one of order $3$. The former are not even normal (i.e., not even invariant under *internal* automorphisms); the latter is necessarily characteristic because its image under an automorphism must again be a subgroup of order $3$ - and there is only one.

Answer (score 1):

$A_3$ is characteristic in that group.

Comment: Why ? can you extension ?